# Problem about Reduce when using MomentGeneratingFunction for a ParameterMixtureDistribution: Too slow

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I use the following code to calculate the MGF of $\lambda_{t+1}$. However, it posts a message about `Reduce`. My guess is that the parameter values are not restricted, so `Reduce` cannot determine the sign of terms in the message.

In addition, this piece of code is very slow to run (a few minutes). I am not sure if this is due to the `Reduce` problem or is there any way I can improve the code to make it run faster?

I find that in this particular case, if I replace $\{\epsilon_{c,t+1},\epsilon_{d,t+1}\}\sim BiSNormal/.\{\rho\rightarrow\rho_{cd}\}$ by $\epsilon_{c,t+1}\sim SNormal$, it runs much faster. However, I am not sure why.

```mathematica
SNormal := NormalDistribution[];
BiSNormal := BinormalDistribution[ρ];
ARG1 := ParameterMixtureDistribution[GammaDistribution[ν + Z, c], 
   Z \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[μ/c]];
JDist := CompoundPoissonDistribution[h, GammaDistribution[1, c]];
Subscript[λ, 
  t + 1] := λb + 
   Subscript[ϕ, λσ] Subscript[σ2, t + 1] + 
   Subscript[ϕ, λτ] Subscript[T, t + 1] + 
   Subscript[ϕ, λλ] Subscript[λ, t] + 
   Subscript[J, t + 1];
Subscript[T, t + 1] := 
  Subscript[ϕ, τ] Subscript[T, t] + α Subscript[x, 
    t] + α Sqrt[Subscript[σ2, t]] Subscript[ϵ, 
    c, t + 1] + 
   Subscript[ν, τ] Subscript[ϵ, τ, t + 1];
rvDist := {
   {Subscript[ϵ, c, t + 1], Subscript[ϵ, d, 
      t + 1]} \[Distributed] 
     BiSNormal /. {ρ -> Subscript[ρ, cd]},
   Subscript[σ2, t + 1] \[Distributed] 
     ARG1 /. {ν -> Subscript[ν, σ], 
     c -> Subscript[c, σ], μ -> 
      Subscript[ϕ, σ] Subscript[σ2, t]},
   Subscript[J, t + 1] \[Distributed] JDist /. {h -> Subscript[l, t], 
     c -> ζ},
   Subscript[ϵ, τ, t + 1] \[Distributed] SNormal
   };
assums = 
  Subscript[ν, σ] > 0 && Subscript[c, σ] > 0 && 
   Subscript[ϕ, σ] > 0 && Subscript[σ2, t] > 0;
MomentGeneratingFunction[
 TransformedDistribution[Subscript[λ, t + 1], rvDist], u]
```

[image]